# Laravel 8 Use of undefined constant XXX - assumed 'XXX' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Tags: php, laravel

I am following this tutorial https://laracasts.com/series/billing-with-laravel-cashier/episodes/1.

When I try to load the subscribe page I get the following error.

Use of undefined constant subscribe - assumed 'subscribe' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

This line

```
<form action="{{ route (subscribe.post)}}" method="post" id="payment-form">
```

in the subscribe blade is causing the error. I do not think I am missing anything in the tutorial. But I can not understand what the subscribe.post is referring to.

Answer (score 5):

`subscribe.post` is referring to a route named `'subscribe.post'` (the `POST` `/subscribe` route). This should be a string:

```
route('subscribe.post')
```

Comment: This made it so I can access the page but when I submit the form it goes to this route http://127.0.0.1:8000/route (subscribe.post)

Comment: Here is my route

Route::post('/subscribe', function (request $request) {
    dd ($request->all());
    return view('subscribe');
})->middleware(['verified'])->name('subscribe.post');